# BouncyCastle Java - Decoding DER encoded OCTET strings

Tags: java, bouncycastle, der

I'm reading in a CER certificate file which gives me an X.509 certificate object.

There are several extensions that contain DER encoded OCTET strings. e.g.:

```
Certificate Extensions: 9
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10 Criticality=false
Extension unknown: DER encoded OCTET string =
0000: 04 1C 30 1A 30 0A 06 0B   2B 06 01 04 01 82 37 2F  ..0.0...+.....7/
0010: 01 01 30 0E 06 08 2B 06   01 05 05 07 03 02        ..0...+.......
```

How can I decode these strings using BouncyCastle

Comment: What did you try, where does it go wrong?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, because I'm not sure how to approach it.
I'm thinking I probably need to use org.bouncycastle.asn1 but I'm  not sure which of the methods to use and how to parse in the extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.com) told me to look at the class: `JcaX509ExtensionUtils`

Now it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks Frank I missed that one! I was looking at the org.bouncycastle.asn1 classes.